# What does impossibliity mean in gnu make -p?

Tags: gnu-make

I am having trouble with a make file and when I run make -p under the directories section I get:

```
adminSrc (device 2049, inode 15991947): 5 files, 1 impossibilities.
```

That is a directory I am having trouble with so I am suspicious it is the cause.

I have searched for this, no reference in GNU make docs, I looked in some stat docs, no joy.  Google has the question asked in a usenet thread, but there was no reply.

So, what does impossibilities mean?  I suspect filesystem corruption, is that true?  Will it break rules referring to that directory?

Here are the makefile fragments at issue

```
canvasserDest/%.js: canvasserSrc/%.js
    jsx canvasserSrc canvasserDest

adminDest/%.js: adminSrc/%.js
    jsx adminSrc adminDest
```

and

```
scripts/enterApp.js: admin/enter.js adminDest/enterJXS.js
    browserify admin/enter.js > scripts/enterApp.js
```

in bash

```
jrootham@Doonesbury:~/dev/campaign$ ls adminSrc/
assignJSX.js  enterJSX.js  recruitJSX.js

jrootham@Doonesbury:~/dev/campaign$ make

make: *** No rule to make target `adminDest/enterJXS.js', needed by `scripts/enterApp.js'.  Stop.
```

the canvasserDest rule works fine, the adminDest rule does not.   What am I doing wrong?

I was looking for typos and bad invisible characters but looking at the makefile with od does not show anything.

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: Can you put that in the question so the formatting isn't horrible?

Comment: You have `JXS` instead of `JSX` in `adminDest/enterJXS.js` in the prereq.

Comment: That looks like it.  Thank you.  Care to make it an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 2):

Quick source dive in make 3.81 (also 3.82 and 4.0) seems to indicate that it means that a file in that directory was attempted to be searched for as an intermediate file but failed to be found that way.

From `dir.c`:

```
/* Mark FILENAME as `impossible' for `file_impossible_p'.
   This means an attempt has been made to search for FILENAME
   as an intermediate file, and it has failed.  */
```

If you look for lines that say "Rejecting impossible ..." those are likely related to the files in that count.

And to answer the underlying problem that caused the question about impossible files.

> You have JXS instead of JSX in adminDest/enterJXS.js in the prereq.

Comment: Any indication about why the attempt failed?

Comment: No. I don't think `make` gives you that indication. But I don't think that this is always indicative of a real problem.